# Is there any c# code for deleting cosmos DB documents

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, sql-delete

I am working on an .net api development in which one task is deletes some documents based on the condition .The documents is resided in Cosmos DB.

I have tried via stored procedures but  didnt get proper SP which deleted record.I have tried fetching the documents using select query with where condition and by loop through it fetched and passed document ID and I've tried to delete 
`using DeleteDocumentAsync`

```
//---Deleting Document based on documentId from corresponding DbName,CollectionName-----------//

 private async Task DeleteSecurityDocument(string databaseName, string collectionName, string documentName)
        {

                string endPoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocDbEndPoint"];
                string masterKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocDbmasterKey"];

                var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endPoint), masterKey);

                await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseName, collectionName, documentName));    

        }
```

Comment: I've never used Cosmos before. But some easy Googling shows that [DeleteDocumentAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.deletedocumentasync?view=azure-dotnet) returns a response object, and you're ignoring it. Did you try inspecting that to see what information it might tell you?

Comment: Is your collection partitioned? Also which Cosmos DB API are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me:

```
var options = new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(PartitionKeyValue) };
var docUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseId, collectionId, documentId);
var doc = await _client.ReadDocumentAsync(docUri, options);

if (doc != null)
{
    return await _client.DeleteDocumentAsync(doc.SelfLink, options);
}
```

where `options` is an instance of `RequestOptions` and *should have PartitionKey set if you are working with partitioned collection*.

Most probably reading the document before deleting is not necessary here, and you can directly put docUri, I haven't checked this (the code exists in the project for a long time).

Comment: Thanks For the help.                                                                                         
var docUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseName, collectionName, documentName);
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.RequestOptions options = null;
await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(docUri, options);   I have used this but not Worked..var doc = await _client.ReadDocumentAsync(docUri, options); I have tried this line but get null and Selflink is not enabled. I am not familiar with this cosmos DB..Can anyone help me?

Comment: If ReadDocumentAsync returns null, it means that the document with this identifier is not found. Make sure that in this line ```var docUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseId, collectionId, documentId)``` you pass correct values: database name, collection name and *the value of "id" property of your document*. Another important thing - if your collection is partitioned, make sure you pass correct value of PartitionKey in request options. E.g. if partition key on your collection is called "tenantId", you need to pass the value of document.tenantId to PartitionKey  property.

Answer (score 0):

```
/---------------.delete documents ------------/
var docUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseName, collectionName, documentName);
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(Partitionkeyvalue) };
var deleteresponse = await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(docUri, options);
```

Now it works fine  for me .Problem was about partitiokeyvalue. Thanks

Comment: this should be a comment on the other question, and you should Accept that answer

Comment: note I also added the relevant line of code into that answer